# How to run firebase emulators for local development with functions, triggers on remote db?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, localhost, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm building a firebase API with cloud functions and want to reach my production Database for local testing.
My problem :

---

When I launch my two firebase emulator (functions and firestore) with

```
firebase emulators:start
```

1- My custom API endpoints run on http://localhost:5001 (this works)

2- My triggers reaches a local dababase on http://localhost:8080 whereas I didn't set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080 (**I want to reach my production database**)

### OR

When I launch only my "functions emulator" with

```
firebase emulators:start --only function
```

...but my triggers are not reached, probably because of this warning

```
i  functions[userOnCreate]: function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.
```

---

On the other side I'm building a reactjs App also with firebase running on localhost:3000

I call my local API from this app with firebase SDK. To reach my emulator, I add the line :

```
firebase.functions.useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local emulators don't work with actual cloud-hosted instances of databases.  Everything must be local.

You are always free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: At the beginning, I only inited a "functions project" with `firebase init functions` (without firestore emulator)... I'm almost certain I already tested my undeployed triggers this way . It is possible or i'm dreaming ?

Comment: You can locally test an HTTP trigger that accesses any database, but you can't locally test a database trigger that fires in response to changes on a remote database.  You would have to use the functions shell to simulate a database change that fires the function.

Comment: oh yes, sorry. It was with `firebase functions:shell` I remember now... 

Comment: Local emulator do work with cloud-hosted instances, if you set your database config in your firebase functions config then run the emulator, then the emulator would consume what's in your firebase config. 

firebase functions:config:set or edit your .runtimeconfig.json

If you don't want to use the emulator and call your cloud functions from your local then use firebase serve with the right account.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `firebase serve` instead for `firebase emulators:start`

Comment: can you see the emulator UI if you just `firebase serve`?